# Should I be caching the assets in my asset manager, or will the browser handle it?

Tags: javascript

I use the asset manager class below in my game to download all the game data at launch. It's about 5000 files. Each file is retrieved like so:

```
const image = AssetsManager.getImage("rooms.lounge.floor");
```

Will the browser cache these itself or should I add a caching layer myself?

```
import {
    ASSET_URL
} from 'src/AssetsManager';

export default class AssetsManager {

    static resolveUrl(path)
    {
        path = path.split('.').join('/');

        return ASSET_URL + path;
    }

    static async getJSON(path)
    {
        const url = AssetsManager.resolveUrl(path) + '/.json';

        return fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
    }

    static async getImage(path)
    {
        const image = new Image();
        const url   = AssetsManager.resolveUrl(path) + '/.png';

        image.onload = () => {
            if (image.complete) Promise.resolve(image);
            Promise.reject();
        }
        image.src = url;
    }
```

Comment: If you have code that currently works, and you want feedback on coding style/efficiency/best practices, you might want to ask on the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. That's their wheelhouse.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch(url)` will always reload the resource from the web. So when you request the resource several times and you don't think it changed in the meantime, then you should really consider to add a caching layer.

When you load an image with `image.src = url;`, then the browser will usually load that image from cache if it is cached. But keep in mind that the browser might discard the image from memory if it isn't used and its caching settings don't require it to stay cached.

Loading 5000 files at game start might result in a quite long startup loading time. This is quite problematic for web games, because the average attention span of users on the web is rather short. Every second of startup delay will cause more people to just close the website. You might want to consider some strategy which allows you to load most assets while the game is already running... or at least create a very promising looking preload animation.

Also, you should be aware of that you are using several Javascript features which are very new. It might not work on some user's web browsers.